# Use value from one function into another without returning in python

Tags: python

I am facing a problem sending a variable value from one function to another.
This is my first function:

```
def get_balance(id, current_session, msg_result, r_type):
    session_vals = du.get_session_vals(id)
    bal = session_vals['balance']
    bal = 2345
    if r_type == "f":
        return cu.get_ccy_formatted(bal)
    else:
        return bal * float(validate_currency.result)
```

And the second functions looks like this

```
def validate_currency(id, msg):
    print("Validating currency code")
    cur_list = ['840', '356', 'USD', 'INR', '967', 'ZMW']

    msg = msg.upper()

    if msg in cur_list:
        return True
    else:
        return False

    api_key = '********'
    import requests, json
    base_url = r"https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE"

    from_curr = 'USD'
    to_curr = msg

    main_url = base_url + "&from_currency=" + from_curr + "&to_currency=" + to_curr 
    + "&apikey=" + api_key 

    req_ob = requests.get(main_url) 
    result = req_ob.json()
    result = result["Realtime Currency Exchange Rate"] ['5. Exchange Rate']
```

What I want here is to use the result value from the `validate_currency` function in `get_balance` function. I cannot return the `result` as my flow of code requires `validate_currency` function to return either true or false.
Is there any way, I can use the value from second function into first without returning it explicitly?

Comment: Consider why you want to use a variable from one function in another. Can you duplicate the code that calculates `result` in `get_balance`? Can you extract the code into a third function?

Comment: Does it actually need to return `True` or `False`? Is there some reason it can't just return a truthy or falsy value of arbitrary type?

Comment: You could use a global variable, or have these functions as class methods and assign the results to class members - however I would reconsider the scope of your functions and what their outputs should be given that you want a `result` but don't want to `return` it - that's exactly what a return should be for!

Comment: I can't see why you couldn't return say a tuple, with the first value being boolean, and the other the result. Having functions mess with each other's state is bad design.

Comment: I cannot return multiple values as the boolean value I am returning from a function is being used to drive the other code. The other code totally depends on whether the value returned from this function is either ```true``` or ```false```.

Comment: You can use ShadowRanger 's or seesharper 's recommendation. Doing so won't effect your code. Prefer **not** to use global variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new argument to have it changed by reference.

```
def validate_currency(id, msg, result):
    print("Validating currency code")
    cur_list = ['840', '356', 'USD', 'INR', '967', 'ZMW']

    msg = msg.upper()

    """
    you can add this code in another
    method then save in a variable to return

    if msg in cur_list:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    """

    api_key = '********'
    import requests, json
    base_url = r"https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE"

    from_curr = 'USD'
    to_curr = msg

    main_url = base_url + "&from_currency=" + from_curr + "&to_currency=" + to_curr 
    + "&apikey=" + api_key 

    req_ob = requests.get(main_url) 
    result = req_ob.json()
    result = result["Realtime Currency Exchange Rate"] ['5. Exchange Rate']
```

So the function call would look like this

```
result = None
validate_currency(id=id, msg='any message', result=result)
print(result) # result with value
```

See: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference